# Help for substitute of a gym device

Tags: abdominals, getting-in-shape

In my local gym, the *butterfly* device of the multi-gym in not working properly. I want to have proper shapes and cuts of my body especially my abdomen part. Can anyone give a suitable substitute device or workout? Well I mean this..

[image: This is what I mean by a _Buttefly_ machine]

Comment: Do you have a picture of this "butterfly" device?  It almost sounds like a pec deck machine.  If it is, that machine does not work the abs.

Comment: Being, what you call 'cut' is always related to proper diet and calculated calorie restriction - exercise is a lesser factor

Comment: They might be referring to the a(b/d)ductor machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont understand the part with the relation of butterflies, cuts and abs, but  some substitutes are:

- dumbbell flys (flat bench)
  https://youtu.be/eozdVDA78K0
- wide grip push ups 
  https://youtu.be/rr6eFNNDQdU
- furniture glider flys/and two roller or dumbbell push up roll out
  https://youtu.be/of5LbG_Vlm8 and
  https://youtu.be/zm1Bo_QBZ_c
- resistence band flys
  https://youtu.be/5qdUoUFWTJs
- dips with elbows out  (not close to the body)
  https://youtu.be/y3NIbM7_H_A
- one arm bench presses with max ROM
  https://youtu.be/TVM2S2KWX6Q
- TRX bodyweight flys
  https://youtu.be/XfhT_WYEbJk

Comment: I gave an image . Now I do hope the things you have stated above do substitute the above device. @mitro

Comment: Yes they do, this looks like a 'butterfly'-machine and not an 'abs'-machine

Comment: Can you suggest some link(s) (like a YouTube one) where I can get information about all the substitutes . I prefer a video link , as I am a beginner and I want to see the correct steps for each of these substitutes .(Wrong steps can cause damage) and I don't have a trainer.

Comment: Done changed the answer accordingly

Comment: I AM EXTREMELY GRATEFUL TO YOU. Had I been given a chance of a second up-vote to an answer , I would have up-voted your answer twice.

Comment: No worries, hope you have fun in your training ... cheers